# IBM Blockchain api - status endpoint

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, ibm-blockchain

I have been working on deployment scripts for a business network via composer to IBM blockchain cloud, every example i have seen includes a request to the endpoint.

`/api/v1/networks/${BLOCKCHAIN_NETWORK_ID}/sample/${BLOCKCHAIN_SAMPLE_ID}`

From [Here](https://github.com/yefrigaitanrosales/blockchain-starter/blob/master/.bluemix/pipeline-BLOCKCHAIN.sh)

However this endpoint is not visible in the [swagger UI](https://blockchain-starter.eu-gb.bluemix.net/api-docs/#/) - and i am unable to find any reference anywhere to what it actually does - ive not included it in my scripts and its caused no issues.

Can anyone shed any light on what it does.

Comment: see https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/blockchain-document-store/solution-manager-api.html#blockchain-solution-manager-api

Comment: Good spot, but still nothing about /sample/xxxxx